# Generics related problem

Tags: java, generics

My code is as below:

```
private <A extends AbstractDocument> List<A> reorderDocuments(List<A> docs)
    {
        List<A> newdoclist = new ArrayList<A>();
        for (A o : docs) {
            if(//some condition) {
                //TODO::Generic type
                List<A> tempDocs = new ArrayList<A>();
                tempDocs.add( o );
                tempDocs.addAll(o.getAlikeDocuments());
                //sort method called
            } 
          return newdoclist;
    }
```

have changed the start tag for the type with the function `o.getAlikeDocuments()` returns List of type Abstract document, but this method is still giving me error on line `tempDocs.addAll(o.getAlikeDocuments());` saying The method `addAll(Collection<? extends A>)` in the type List is not applicable for the arguments `(List<AbstractDocument>)`.
Appreciate the help in advance.

Thanks

Vaibhav

Comment: Format you code using the {} button and not directly with HTML

Comment: Also, you should accept some answer!

Comment: i accepted ur answer by clicking on the correct sign hope that suffices :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you have is that `A` is a subclass of `AbstractDocument` and you may not add any `AbstractDocument` except sub-classes of `A`

To make it compile, if you know this is not a problem is to use type erasure.

```
 tempDocs.addAll((List) o.getAlikeDocuments());
```

Comment: Only if he's sure that o.getAlikeDocuments() will definitely return a List of objects of type A (or sub-type). It looks like the return type of this method is List<AbstractDocument> which means, if he uses your solution, he could end up adding AbstractDocument objects to a List<AbstractDocumentSubType>.

Comment: just noticed you did say "if you know this is not a problem"

Comment: Yeah it makes sense for me cos the return type of this method would always be AbstractDocument, Thanks for the help! appreciate it!

Comment: But only if you're sure, at runtime, that the objects returned by o.getAlikeDocuments() will be of type A (or a sub-type). If they are of type AbstractDocument then the code that calls reorderDocuments() can end up with a List<AbstractDocumentSubType> that contains an AbstractDocument object which could cause all kinds of problems.

Comment: In which case the method should return a List<AbstractDocument> ;)

Answer (score 0):

Casting to a raw list will do the trick

```
tempDocs.addAll((List) o.getAlikeDocuments());
```

The following page might help to memorize the restrictions of extends and super

[What is PECS (Producer Extends Consumer Super)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/java-generics-what-is-pecs)